# realloc strange memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, realloc

I have a n-ary tree:

```
struct node {
    char *data;
    int numofkids;
    struct node **kids;
}
```

and a function:

```
addToParent(struct node *parent, struct node *kid);
```

that attaches a kid to a parent.

I do that by reallocing the kids array of the father every time I want to add a new kid.

The body:

```
  parent->numofkids ++;
  parent->kids = realloc(parent->kids, parent->numofkids * sizeof(char *));
  parent->kids[(parent->numofkids) - 1] = kid;
```

I run my program using valgrind --leak-check=yes ./myprog and it shows memory leaks from realloc function of addToParent function. That means I have to free() something? But what? I am not removing kids, I am just adding the given kid to the given parent.

Valgrind:

[image: Valgrind output]

Comment: This might not be the problem you're having, but never call realloc like that. If it fails, then you'll be left with a memory leak and a nullptr.

Comment: yes you should always `void *newptr = realloc(oldptr, newsize); if (newptr == NULL) {free(oldptr); doSomethingAboutIt();} else  oldptr = newptr`. But that's not enought to know what is causing it, you need to post the code and the valgrind output too.

Comment: Maybe you're just leaking nodes or don't free `kids` when freeing a node?

Comment: i updated with the code and the valgrind output

Comment: too small.  replace to text.

Comment: How does *that* valgrind report indicate `addToParent` is the culprit? Given only what you show my guess would be the original `parent` itself is leaked or the (conveniently omitted) cleanup code that is supposed to free a parent *and* its kids never does the latter. Without seeing the code we simply can't answer that. Ex: you may free the parent and each kid, but not the pointer bed that held the kid pointers. And fyi, every time a *picture* of code or output text is put in a post, a kitten dies. Please paste *real text* in your listings.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to use realloc() is

```
struct node * temp = realloc(parent->kids, parent->numofkids * sizeof(char *));
if(temp != NULL)
parent->kids = temp;
else
{
 /* take necessary action when allocation fails */
}
```

Because `realloc()` can fail and if it fails you will end up losing the original data before the `realloc()` call. Once done using the memory you need to `free()` it.

Comment: Whether `realloc()` can fail, and whether it's worth to write this safeguard depends on the system. Modern systems overcommit their memory and just start killing processes when they can't back up their promises. On such a system, checking the result of `realloc()` is pretty pointless because the `realloc()` call won't fail in most use cases. And you can't safeguard against the OOM-killer.

Comment: @cmaster: There are other cases in which `realloc()` can fail, other than complete system memory exhaustion. For example, the process may hit a specified limit (see `setrlimit`), or (especially running on a 32-bit system) run out of address space in which to `mmap()` a new segment.

Comment: This does not tell OP where the leak is. If the `realloc` *failed*, the OP would get a segfault on his next line (writing into the NULL pointer). If it *succeeds* there would not be a memory leak to report.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a bunch of potential problems in that code, or in the code calling it (which you haven't shown).

Firstly, the size allocated should be in related to the size of the object being allocated.   Not to a multiple of `sizeof(char *)`.

Second, `realloc()` returns `NULL` if it fails, and that should be checked for, rather than assuming it succeeds.

Based on these, you need to do something like this

```
struct node **temp = realloc(parent->kids, (parent->numofkids+1)*sizeof(*temp));
if (temp != NULL)
{
    parent->kids = temp;
    ++parent->numofkids;
    parent->kids[parent->numofkids - 1] = kid;
}
else
{
     /*  reallocation failed, so leave the pointers alone and complain bitterly */
}
```

The other things to check;

1. Since you're passing in a pointer to a `struct node`, check whether the object being passed is valid (e.g. it is not an uninitialised pointer) and that it is being released by the caller when done.
2. Check that `parent` points at something value before the first call of your function, and that it is released before the program ends.
3. Check that ALL of the things you've dynamically allocated (or reallocated) are actually released before the program ends.